# multi level dependency unit test C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I've 3 classes: Class A, Class B and Class C.

```
Class A
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        var b = new B();
        b.doSomething();
    } 
}

Class B
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        var c = new C();
        c.doSomething();
    }
}

Class C
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        //do something
    }   
}
```

I've to make the above code testable. So i am planning to make use of Dependency Injection. After refactoring my code looks like this

```
public interface InterfaceB
{
    void doSomething();
}

public class A
{
    private InterfaceB _b;

    public A(InterfaceB b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        _b.doSomething();
    }
}

public interface InterfaceC
{
    void doSomething();
}  

public class B : InterfaceB
{
    private InterfaceC _c;

    public B(InterfaceC c)
    {
        _c = c;
    }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        _c.doSomething();
    }
}

public class C : InterfaceC
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        // do something
    }
}

Main()
{
    var a = new A(new ClassB());
}
```

I am clear with the first level of dependency injection. How do i go about with the second level of dependency injection with my ClassB in turn dependant on ClassC.

Help is appreciated.

Regards,
Suyog

Comment: What exactly is not clear?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've already setup all dependency injection. `B` is injected in `A` and `C` is injected in `B`. Just create an instance like this: `var a = new A(new ClassB(new ClassC));`

Comment: Will A take B and C interfaces? What i read is A should not be aware of C as it is only dependent on B.

Comment: In Joroen's example, A is not aware of C--the class *creating* A (Main()) is aware of C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you writing unit-tests for class `A` you should provide only mocks of it's **direct** dependencies, i.e. in your case it will be mock of `InterfaceB`:

```
 private void AShouldDelegateWorkToB()
 {
     Mock<InterfaceB> bMock = new Mock<InterfaceB>();     
     A a = new A(bMock.Object);
     a.DoSomething();
     bMock.Verify(b => b.DoSomething(), Times.Once);
 }
```

You should not care about implementation of `B` - whether it delegates its work to some other class `C` or does all by itself. That's details of the class `B` implementation, which should be tested by tests of class `B`. Remember, class `A` even don't know about class `B` existence - that's just one of possible implementations of `InterfaceB` (just like your mock object).